# Why is this not working, And how do you debug code in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

First I'm trying to learn nodejs, and for that I am writing like a router. As you have in express.

This is my code:

```
function sirus() {
    var util = utilFuncs(),
        paths = {};
    this.router = util.handleReq;
    this.con = {
        get: function (path, fn, options) {
            options = (options || {}).method = "GET";
            util.makeRequest(path, fn, options);
        },
        post: function (path, fn, options) {
            options = (options || {}).method = "POST";
            util.makeRequest(path, fn, options);
        }
    };
    this.req = {
        get: function (path, fn) {
            util.addPath("GET", path, fn);
        },
        post: function (path, fn) {
            util.addPath("POST", path, fn);
        }
    };

    function utilFuncs() {
        function handleReq(req, res) {
            var url = parsePath(req.url);
            var path = paths[req.method + url];
            // console.log(req.url, url +' requested');
            if (typeof path != "function") {
                res.writeHead(404);
            } else {
                path(req, res);
            }
            res.end();
        }

        function addPath(type, path, callback) {
            // add path as a key of object for easier look up, root=/, /a=/a, /a/=/a, /a?=/a, /a/?..=/a so there are no duplicates path=parsePath(path);
            paths[type + path] = callback;
        }

        function parsePath(path) {
            path = url.parse(path).pathname;
            if ((/[^\/]+\/(?=$)/igm).test(path)) path = path.substring(0, path.length - 1);
            return path;
        }

        function makeRequest(path, fn, options) {
            var urls = url.parse(path);
            var d = {
                host: null,
                hostname: null,
                method: "GET",
                path: '/',
                port: 80,
                headers: {},
                auth: null,
                agent: false,
                keepAlive: false
            };
            for (var k in options) d[k] = options[k];
            d.host = urls.host;
            d.hostname = urls.hostname;
            d.path = urls.pathname;
            d.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
            d.headers['Content-Length'] = ((d || {}).body || {}).length || '';
            var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
                // console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
                // console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
                res.setEncoding('utf8');
                var data = '';
                res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                    data += chunk;
                });
                res.on('end', function (chunk) {
                    data += chunk;
                });
                res.on('response', function () {
                    fn(res);
                });
            });
            req.on('error', function (e) {
                console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
            });
            req.write(d.body);
            req.end();
        }
        return {
            makeRequest: makeRequest,
            handleReq: handleReq,
            addPath: addPath
        };
    }

}
```

and i use it like this:

```
var http = require('http'),
    url = require('url'),
    app = new sirus();

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    app.router(req, res);
}).listen(80, '127.0.0.1');


app.req.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    var link = "https://www.reddit.com/";
    res.write('<a href="' + link + '">Click here</a>');
});

app.con.get('http://www.google.com/', function (res) {
    console.log('from req: ' + res);
});
```

The error i get is **The First argument must be string or buffer**
Receiving part works correctly, but when i started to add make request part something isn't right.

Also since I'm new to JS and Nodejs. I'd like general advice or anything that catch your eye something that i can be improved about this code. Since I'm note sure i am doing things the best way.

Comment: where are you getting error?. It will be helpful if you show exact error message.

Comment: You should provide more detailed error (it usually tells you the file and line in which error happened.

Comment: that's the thing it's telling that error occurred somewhere in http module line 413. Which is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 1):

On line 85

```
req.write(d.body);
```

there is no member named "body" in the "d" object.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Why is this not working - you get exactly error that tells you why it is not working. If you check more details about error it shows the file and which line error happened at. Perhaps the arguments you pass to function call are not what Express is expecting.

2 - How to debug - look at node.js package called [`nodev`](https://github.com/akamensky/nodev).

Comment: error happened in http module, however, almost everything in my code is using http module. But i can tell you this, the error has to do with making request part not receiving request. And thanks ill be checking out that

Comment: @MuhammadUmer please use proper debugging tools to find which code generated this error. It usually easy to find out. Also when debugging check out the callee property that will show you which function in your code called method when error occurred.

Comment: ok i tried using it, but the inspector keeps crashing "detached from target" same error for even other projects that work. Could be window only problem..

Comment: @MuhammadUmer node.js is known to have issues under Windows as it is not really meant for Windows. Suggest to look at Vagrant if Windows system is the only choice on your side.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer FYI, just updated nodev package with latest dependencies, maybe that will help running it on Windows (which I actually doubt).